# I cannot reproduce an IE/JavaScript error using BrowserStack or a VM. What are my options?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging

IE7 and 8 users on a website I maintain experience JavaScript errors that I can't reproduce.

I have set up modern.ie virtual machines with Windows 7, Vista and XP, as well as viewing the site in those browsers on BrowserStack. I've tried turning quirks mode on and off. I've found an old PC and looked at the site on that. None of these methods has successfully reproduced any of the errors.

Before I actually go round to their office (which is hundreds of miles from mine, needless to say), is there anything else I ought to to try in order to reproduce these bugs?

Comment: the best thing to do is go to the machine having the problem.

Comment: @DanielA.White, thank you. I would like to be sure that I've covered all the bases first.

Comment: Did you get them to provide the error details to you (double clicking the little yellow asterisk symbol that appears at the bottom left)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by different versions of Flash on the different computers.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you don't have any browser extension/plugins that may cause the issue. But if you don't tell us what the bugs are we're going to have trouble helping you.

You may also try to debug using remote desktop you won't have to go round to their office.

Comment: Remote desktop - good idea! Thank you for the feedback. It's impossible to be more specific, as I can't reproduce the bugs. All I know is that JS execution stops because all JS on the page stops working.

Comment: Do they have javascript disabled? Via browser settings? You can actually do that... its just not been done in like.... ever.